# Filtering specific number / removing text

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

This is what my cell looks like, and I'm only supposed to have the mobile phone number (just the number, no text at all). However, I'm not sure which formula to go with, because mid/left/right aren't exactly helpful here (different length of numbers, links, words).

[image]

Comment: These all texts is in a single cell or each line in each cell?

Comment: All in a single cell

Comment: You could try: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[2] = 'Mobile']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text is in cell $A$1:

1. The mobile phone number (digits) begin at:

`=FIND("Mobile phone: +",$A$1)+LEN("Mobile phone: +")`

2. Assuming the mobile phone number is not followed by space characters, its length is:

`=FIND("Phone: +",$A$1)-(FIND("Mobile phone: +",$A$1)+LEN("Mobile phone: +")+1)`

3. So the mobile phone's numeric value is:

`=VALUE(MID($A$1,FIND("Mobile phone: +",$A$1)+LEN("Mobile phone: +"),FIND("Phone: +",$A$1)-(FIND("Mobile phone: +",$A$1)+LEN("Mobile phone: +")+1)))`

You could also use the `Between` function found in [My Excel Toolbox](https://sites.google.com/view/MyExcelToolbox/). Here is a simplified version of that function:

```
Function Between(Text, BeginAfter, EndBefore)
    nFirst = InStr(1, Text, BeginAfter)
    If nFirst > 0 Then nFirst = nFirst + Len(BeginAfter)
    nLast = InStr(nFirst, Text, EndBefore) - 1
    Between = Mid(Text, nFirst, (nLast - nFirst + 1))
End Function
```

The complete version has more features. For your example:

`=TRIM(CLEAN(Between($A$1,"Mobile phone: +","Phone: +")))`

Comment: Worked only when I took out "value", that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A use for the new `LET` function (in O365) (***and this will retain leading zero's in the phone number***)

```
=MID(LET(X,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A10,CHAR(10)," "))," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQUENCE(99)*99,99)),INDEX(X,2+MATCH("Mobile",X,0))),2,99)
```

- The `LET` function allows the same calculation to be used twice in the formula

  - We split the string into an array of space-separated words which is used in the `LET`

```
        TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A10,CHAR(10)," "))," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQUENCE(99)*99,99))
```

- Look for the position (index) of the word: `Mobile`

  ```
   MATCH("Mobile",X,0)
  ```
- Add two (2) to that position to get the mobile phone number
- Use the `MID` function to strip off the leading `+`.

  - Omit the `MID` if you want to include the leading `+`
  - Replace the `MID` with `SUBSTITUTE` if some numbers don't have the leading `+`, or check some other way if that will result in unwanted returns.

Comment: Some of us with O365 have not received the LET function yet, but it should have been added long ago.